# Error in Thymeleaf Rendering HTML

Tags: jquery, html, spring, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf with a Spring application. When I load the index.html, pulling in bootstrap, jQuery and some custom stylesheets, some of the scripts are pulled in twice as shown below:

```
</body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">         </script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="../static/js/material.min.js" th:src="@{/js/material.min.js}"></script>

    <script src="../static/js/nouislider.min.js" type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/nouislider.min.js}"></script>

    <script src="../static/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js}"></script>

    <script src="../static/js/material-kit.js" type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/material-kit.js}"></script>

</html>
    </THYMELEAF_ROOT>-->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="/js/material.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../static/js/nouislider.min.js" type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/nouislider.min.js}"></script>

    <script src="../static/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js}"></script>

    <script src="../static/js/material-kit.js" type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/material-kit.js}"></script>

</html>
    </THYMELEAF_ROOT>-->

    <script src="/js/nouislider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../static/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js}"></script>

    <script src="../static/js/material-kit.js" type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/material-kit.js}"></script>

</html>
    </THYMELEAF_ROOT>-->

    <script src="/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../static/js/material-kit.js" type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/material-kit.js}"></script>

</html>
    </THYMELEAF_ROOT>-->

    <script src="/js/material-kit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Also, some parts of the html is repeated as shown below and there are those THYMELEAF_ROOT tags. I have viewed the html in the browser without running it through a server and it displays fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem. This is incase someone else is having similar issues. For some reasons, Thymeleaf does not handle `HTML` comments properly. So when I removed all the comments, it rendered the `HTML` properly.